# Spring boot micro services enable Https when running inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I have some spring boot micro services and I have enabled https.

Basically I have a config service, a discovery service and an app service. 
The config service contains the property files for the discovery and the app service. 
When the discovery and app service starts they load their properties from the config server.
Each service contains each own keystore file with a self signed certificate. 
On a local machine they are working properly and I can access all of them through https.
Here is what I have:

config_srvc:

```
security:
  require-ssl: true
server:
  port: 8888
  ssl:
    enabled: true 
    key-store-type: PKCS12
    key-store: classpath:keystore-config-devel.p12
    key-alias: config-devel
    key-store-password: password
    key-password: password
    ...
```

discovery_srvc:

```
eureka:
      instance:
        hostname: localhost 
    server:
      ssl:
        key-store-type: PKCS12
        key-store: classpath:keystore-discovery-devel.p12
        key-alias: discovery-devel
        key-store-password: password
        key-password: password
...
```

When I tried to run them inside a docker container (using network=host), the config server is starting successfully and I can access the property files through browser (https://localhost:8888/discovery/devel) but after I try to start the discovery service I get the following error:

```
2018-05-02 09:35:07.094  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at: https://localhost:8888
2018-05-02 09:35:07.481  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "https://localhost:8888/discovery/devel": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any ideas what's the problem with the docker container?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using docker compose to launch both the containers? If not would be able to show the docker run commands?

Comment: No I don't use docker compose. The command is the following: 'docker run -d --network=host --rm -t --name config_srvc config_srvc' and 'docker run -d --network=host --rm -t --name discovery_srvc discovery_srvc'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution

I had to import the certificate inside the docker container jre cacerts. I did it by adding the following in the dockerfile:

```
COPY config.crt $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
RUN \
    cd $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security \
    && keytool -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias config -file config.crt
```